# How do I connect Auth0 to my NextJS frontend after connecting it to my backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, next.js, auth0

So I have connected auth0 to my backend which consists of Node, Express and a MongoDB database. I am able to create accounts and log in using endpoints of my server (localhost:4000/login) but this is not what I want. I am also building a front-end for my application which will be where users are asked to authenticate and only then are they allowed to access protected routes. I need to find a way to connect my auth0 application (that is already connected to my backend) to my frontend.

I am not sure how to implement this so any help on this would be amazing. If this question has been answered or if a resource exists online that tackles this problem, please point me to it.

Comment: I think you should use `next-auth`. It has built-in-support for many popular services (Google, Facebook, Auth0, Apple…). [Next-Auth](https://next-auth.js.org/)

Answer (score 1):

and here help arrived.

Firstly, check this [example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/auth0).

Secondly, here is an idea of how any page in nextjs works with auth0

A. Any page can be secured with auth0. By default your pages are not secured

B. To secure the page you need to:

```
export const getServerSideProps = withPageAuthRequired({
  //returnTo: '/foo',
  async getServerSideProps(ctx) {
    return { props: { customProp: 'bar' } };
  }
});
```

C. You can also secure API endpoints (but in this case it will not be accessible from anywhere except your client, so you couldn't for example access from postman)

```
import { withApiAuthRequired, getAccessToken, getSession } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

    export default withApiAuthRequired(async function test(req, res) {
      try {
        const session = getSession(req, res);
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(error.status || 500).json({
          code: error.code,
          error: error.message
        });
      }
    });
```

D. You can also call, for example, `getSession` almost everywhere to get info about 'clients' connected.

E. You need to also check this [docs](https://auth0.github.io/nextjs-auth0/index.html), this is quite geeky

F. You can secure a `component` also, for example, imagine you created a 'secured' component as `SecuredLayout`. Every time you embed your content with `SecuredLayout` page will trigger the 'login' page to user logins. (useful for `my personal space` for clients). Try always to decompose your elements.

P.S. You need to run your localhost on HTTPS protocol.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comprehensive answer! I am quite confused now since I already have an application on Auth0 that is connected to my node and mongoDB to check for users, how can I use the same application and connect it to my front-end? All the steps you mentioned seems like I would have to make a new app for my nextjs auth0.

Comment: So this case please share some code you are using for backend, like this I can check what you have done.